# features are less but the app size is bigger even in aab format

Tags: nativescript

I'm in trouble because of the app size. It is 44 mb in apk version and 40 mb in aab version.

My app contains only 56 files XML, JS, CSS and 5 images of size 100kb each.

the app folder size is just 2833 kb (or 2.8 mb)

my plugins are

```
 "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "^1.1.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-pager": "^11.0.11",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-pdfview-ng": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0"
```

guys I have tried searching everywhere but none answered this.

even the tns helloworld template when I created it came around 28mb.

none of them considering this seriously. I know it is the problem with the tns-core-module itself as it is the one causing 28 mb size for a basic javascript version helloworld template.

i just need to know what files i need to remove and build the apk.

So that my app size should be below 30mb.

*This is damn simple app guys no one will download. and that too with this much size 'I'm building a failure app'*

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider several things when building an app with NativeScript.

There is a difference in the size of debug build and release build. The release build has several optimizations that can be executed (like uglify, AOT, snapshot + Android App Bundle or ABI Splits), Each of these optimizations will decrease the output size. There is also a difference in the output size of the file and the size of the actual installation file for a specific device.

The output file (for Android) is containing at least 4 different architectures (arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' and `x86_64`) and if you are using ABI Splits and custom flavors that would mean that the output file might contain more than 12 different files that will be used by the Google App Store.

So that said when you publish your alpha/beta in the Google Store, you will notice that the actual size for install on a specific device with a specific architecture and screen size is significantly decreased.

For example, [this relatively mid-size app](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/package.json#L12-L34) which uses several Firebase functionalities and a total of more than 10 native libraries (through the plugins) has an average [of 12MB size in the Google Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.curiosity&hl=en_US).

Note: If your app uses large and heavy assets (like images, movies) that are part of the App_Resources folder than the size will be larger no matter what optimization you do. I recommend using optimized photos (as recommended by Android) and not providing heavy files (like movies) within the resources folder.

Comment: I got release apk and aab, both with size of 36 mb each. This is because the default blank js apk is 28mb which is before ns6 14 mb. now an extra 8 mb is added because of my work. So, earlier i used to get 22mb apk but now I'm getting 36mb apk. This is an issue with tns core plugin itself it seems. And no one was accepting that. and none of you people are checking that by creating a blank js project on windows machine. Hope in future some one will raise a question on this again. Thank you